# Using NAN as not defined value

Tags: c#, undefined, nan

I am working on a CSharp project that displays a double value to the user. This value may not be defined in which case I will display an empty string. When the value is defined it will be greater than or equal to zero. To handle the not defined case, I thought I could define an out of range value, e.g. -1 to represent not defined or wrap the value in a class that has a boolean defined flag. Then I thought, why not just use Double.NAN to signify the value is not defined and Double.IsNAN to check for undefined values. I think this will work, but it just feels a bit wrong. Is it a good idea to use Double.NAN to represent an undefined value?

Comment: I don't feel like there's anything wrong with `NaN`. Another option would be to use a `double?`.

Comment: I'd use a nullable `double` -- i.e. a `double?`

Comment: `Double.NAN` it is equal ambiguity `0/0`. It does  not mean undefined value, I guess you could use nullable class for that like `Double?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [existing wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) `Nullable<double>` or `double?`

```
double? d;

if (d.HasValue)
  Console.WriteLine($"{d.Value}");


Console.WriteLine($"{d.GetValueOrDefault(0)}"); // this will print 0 if value was not defined
```

It better suits I suppose since double.NaN is for result undefined cases for math operations